# How to get products with a specific attribute in a foreach (loop) programmatically?

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, collection

I need to get all products with a specific attribute **example: specialpiece = Yes** with product name, image, price, special_price in a loop to show this in my home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you will need a collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
     ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','image','price','special_price'))
     ->addAttributeToFilter('specialpiece', 1);
```

Then you can loop through them to get their info:

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $name = $product->getName();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $specialPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
    $image = $product->getImage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following code :

```
<?php
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        // add sorting to collection optional
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
   echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';
}
?>
```

For specific attribute  add this line :

```
->addAttributeToFilter('specialpiece ', array("eq" =>1))
```

Comment: where you all putting this code please share with code and file path

Comment: How to get all **$_product->** variables? Ex: getId, getName, getProductUrl ... Sorry for deleted sub-question!!

Comment: If you want to get any product attribute like squ then code will be $_product->getSku();